# Can you run a Shell script or a windows batch file from jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I have a windows batch file and a shell script . Does jmeter have the functionality to run a shell script or a bat file . maybe a plugin or so ? .

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe you can use the javascript or jexl function to do this:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript

Failing that, add a beanshell step and use code to call your script/batch file.

Comment: Answer is outdated since jmeter 2.7

Answer (score 7):

Since jmeter 2.7 there is a new sampler that allows this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler